# How to create a shortcut for a simple app in Sitecore 7?

Tags: web-applications, sitecore, sitecore7

I wrote a simple application using web forms to have data uploaded into Sitecore. This application works fine but I can't get a shortcut created or configure it as an application in the Sitecore desktop. I took the following steps to create an app. I created an application at this location - /sitecore/content/Applications/ with the following template - /sitecore/templates/Sitecore Client/Applications/Application. I entered a path and name for this application.

I then created a shortcut at the following location which points to the above app - /sitecore/content/Documents and settings/All users/Start menu/Left.

I've checked the security on it and it shows read access to the Sitecore Client User and Author roles which I have. I can't see this shortcut in the Master database. Also, I can't see this app as an admin.

I'm using Sitecore 7.2. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: @NikitaSokolsky Looks like u got link wrong for sitecore 8: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40808564/in-sitecore-8-how-can-i-add-a-new-application-to-the-start-menu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I Remember having this issue, Try the following:

Go to the view ribbon, click on “Raw values” and go to the shortcut item and check the application field, it should be something like this (Notice the **.aspx** in url and the  **id** parameter):

```xml
<link text="APP NAME" linktype="internal" url="/Applications/YOURAPPNAME.aspx" id="{GUID}" />
```

Remove the **.aspx** from url and the **id** parameter, like this:

```xml
<link text="APP NAME" linktype="internal" url="/Applications/YOURAPPNAME" />
```

Hit save and reload Sitecore desktop.

Comment: I had to remove spaces from my application item name and then it worked.

Comment: Beaten to it by Ahmed, but I suffered this issue too, and wrote a blog post about it: http://jermdavis.wordpress.com/2014/10/20/a-gotcha-with-custom-applications/