# In Sitecore 8, how can I add a new application to the Start Menu?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

We're using Sitecore 8.1 and would like to add a new app to the Start Menu:

[image: sitecore start menu]

How can one do so?

Answer (score 5):

The required steps are below:

1. Switch to the 'core' database in the bottom-right selector

   [image]
2. Go to Sitecore → Content → Applications, and add a new application
3. Go to Sitecore → Content → Documents and Settings → All Users → Start Menu, and add a new Shortcut to the Left or Right section
4. Go to the new Shortcut, then switch to "Raw Values" mode (in the View tab) and add a link in the following format to the "Application" field:

```xml
<link linktype="internal" url="/Applications/*YOUR APPLICATION NAME*" anchor="" target="" />
```

Now click Save, reload the page, and you should see your new link in the Start Menu.